# php how to push (accumulating) multidimensional array

Tags: php

Please, help with multidimensional array push. Please, see the code and comments below. The push is giving an error. The assigning is giving the last row only.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['page_qstn_answer'])) {
$_SESSION['page_qstn_answer'] = array("page" => array(), "qstn" => array(), "answer" => array()
}
if (!isset($temp)) {
$temp = array("page" => array(), "qstn" => array(), "answer" => array() );
}
while($question = mysqli_fetch_assoc($question_set) ) {
if(isset($question['position']) ){
$post_qstn = $question['position'];
If(isset($_POST[$qstn]) ) {
//printing all rows from db correctly as below
//echo "Question ".$qstn." - selected answer  ".$answer . " on page ".$page ."<br />";
if (isset($temp) ){
$temp = array ("page"=>$page, "qstn"=>$qstn,"answer"=> $answer);}
//show a one by one array rows correctly but $temp has a one row at a time that is Ok
//print_r($temp);
// Try to accumulate $temp into $_Session array. Push is giving an error
//$_SESSION['pages_qstn_answers'] = array_push($_SESSION['pages_qstn_answers'], $temp);
// No error but no accumulation as foreach as below shows the only one last row.
$_SESSION['pages_qstn_answers'] = $temp;
}
foreach ($_SESSION['pages_qstn_answers'] as $key => $value) {
echo "$key = $value\n";}
```

Comment: The error is that my eyes have crossed permanently from looking at that!

Answer (score 0):

I used a function that I found on the website to delete all previously added the same questions before accumulating the $temp entries into the final array as there should be the only one question with a one answer. It seems a working. If somebody could see some shortcomings there please advise. Thanks

```
remove_elm($_SESSION['pages_qstn_answers'], "qstn", $qstn, TRUE);
$_SESSION['pages_qstn_answers'][] = $temp;
function remove_elm($arr, $key, $val, $within = FALSE) {
foreach ($arr as $i => $array)
if ($within && stripos($array[$key], $val) !== FALSE && (gettype($val) === gettype($array[$key])))
unset($arr[$i]);
elseif ($array[$key] === $val)
unset($arr[$i]);
return array_values($arr);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a misunderstanding of how [`array_push()`](http://php.net/array_push) works. It does not return the array, it just appends whatever value you have to it. So when you do:

```
$_SESSION['pages_qstn_answers'] = array_push($_SESSION['pages_qstn_answers'], $temp);
```

The right hand side of the equation simply returns an integer containing the number of elements in the new array. So say you now have 5 elements in your array, you are essentially doing

```
$_SESSION['pages_qstn_answers'] = 5;
```

Instead just do:

```
array_push($_SESSION['pages_qstn_answers'], $temp);
```

or since you're only appending one value I would stick with:

```
$_SESSION['pages_qstn_answers'][] = $temp;
```

Comment: Thank you. for your response. It seems it's starting to accumulate but it's keeping all old entries as I cannot clean it. I'm trying to use unset; =array(); = NULL; but nothing is cleaning the array as all old entries are still there.
The foreach stopped working too as it gives the error as "Notice: Array to string conversion in ..".

Comment: In that case you need to be more clear about what you are trying to do. Try creating a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My apology, Mike, as I added my comment right before your post. If the comment is still not clear I'll try to add an example.
I added $_SESSION['pages_qstn_answers'] = array_unique($_SESSION['pages_qstn_answers'], SORT_REGULAR); and it helps a bit. But, what I need would be the unique page and qstn combination that would show the only a one new answer.